# Vuetify v-row number of elements per row

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue.js with Vuetify and got into Grids.
But somehow I'm unable to specify that I want 3 elements per row.

I've tried

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="3">
    <v-col>Here1</v-col>
    <v-col>Here2</v-col>
    <v-col>Here3</v-col>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

I've even tried passing the col argument to the v-row but with no success...
Anyone knows how I can make the row to print 3 elements per it and then go on new line? I don't seem to even find it in official docs for Vuetify which is strange.
I seen that Bootstrap even has argument right for bs-row to specify number of elements per line. But I can't do the same using Vue and Vuetify... If anyone knows, I'll be really glad to hear how to make it.
Thanks in advance

SOLVED!
I'm dumb a little and forgot that v-row has a space of 12 for v-cols
so

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="4">Here1</v-col>
  <v-col cols="4">Here2</v-col>
  <v-col cols="4">Here3</v-col>
  //Here4 is on new line because there is no space on the first line
  <v-col cols="4">Here4</v-col>
</v-row>
```

Thanks for helping a brother out!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the template wrong, to create what you asked for, the template syntax would be

```
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col cols="3">Here1</v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">Here2</v-col>\
    <v-col cols="3">Here3</v-col>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
<v-container>
```

Comment: Yep, I know how to do this, but the problem is if I add another v-col inside of the v-row it ends up on the same line and I need it to start over on the next line. I know that I can just do another v-row but that's not what I want

Comment: Nevermind, I actually solved it.... Totally forgot that the v-row space is 12... so if I use v-col with 4 it puts exactly 3 elements on the line and then the next ends up on the new line...

Comment: Umm okay, I guess?